# fax software for linux

Tags: linux, fax

I'd like to build an email to fax gateway. The OS will be Linux. It will periodically check an email address via POP3 and derive the fax number, etc, from the email. The email will be encrypted to prevent "fax spam". I need to be able to specify the details via the CLI - so GUI software is a bad idea.

The question is, what is some good FOSS CLI fax software for Linux? Why do you recommend it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hylafax.](http://www.hylafax.org/content/Main_Page)   Works flawlessly.  Simple instructions, complex abilities.  Works great with USB modems.  Free. Active development.  Of course I recommend it.  :)

Comment: And if you need a web front end.  Take a look at AvantFax

Comment: AvantFax looks cool! I guess this will be useful for keeping track of the faxes that were sent and if one wants to send on manually.